# Image size recovery with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

hi I would like to create a site where around an image you can see radial writing (link) (like sun rays). In fact I tried to put the image and through canvas I am trying to superimpose a circle and then connect the radial writings to it (a next step would be to make the writings move) however in fact I cannot generate the canvas rectangle of the same size image (to then have the right proportions to create the circle). I've tried getAttribute or $ {nameclass.width} and others. but i can't recover the image size with javascript.
(On css I use the percentages to have a better adaptation with the subsequent implementations of @media)

```
<canvas id="myCanvas" >Error</canvas>

  <div  >
    <img class="logo_centrale" src="img.png" alt="Errore" >
    <script>
         document.getElementById("myCanvas").style.border = ' 3px solid #f00 ' ;
         document.write(document.getElementsByClassName("logo_centrale").width);
         var l = document.getElementsByClassName("logo_centrale").width;/*doesn't work*/
         var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
         var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
         ctx.beginPath();
         ctx.strokeStyle = ' #fff ';
         l = l / 2 ;
         a = a / 2 ;
         ctx.arc( l , a ,200,0,2*Math.PI);
         ctx.stroke();
   </script>
  </div>
```

```
body {
  position: fixed;
  background-color: black;
}
*{
  border: dashed;
  border-color: white;
}
.logo_centrale{   
z-index: -1;
    max-width: 45%;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    margin-top: 10%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;

}

#myCanvas{  z-index: 2;
    position:absolute;
    width: 630px;
    height: 430px;
    margin-top: 11%;
    margin-left: 27.3%;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to wait for the image to be ready before trying to get the size, then you can use `.width` and `.height`:

```
<img class="logo_centrale" src="img.png" alt="Errore" onload="process(event)">
<script>
    function process(event) {
         console.log(event.target.width)
         console.log(event.target.height)
         // your canvas code
    }
</script>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/geb58asc/

Comment: There is the possibility of not using onload on the tag and calling it through the class name or id

Comment: you have to wait for the image to be loaded, you can fetch the element by class/id and then attach the event listener with code `document.querySelector('.logo_centrale').onload = ...`. But the problem is that, if the image happens to load before you attach the event then the event will never fire.

Another option is to have the image with no `src` attribute and, with code, first you add the onload event listener and then you set the src, that way it should work.

If you don't want to use onload you can use some setTimeout hack, but onload is the correct callback to use to be sure it loaded

Comment: doesn t work, i try both solution

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/andrea97/42dgxa8m/6/#&togetherjs=d7sEP9qPtA

Comment: You are setting the `src` attribute in the function that runs when the `onload` callback is triggered, but your image has no `src` at the beginning so it will never trigger the `onload` event. you can do something like this to properly attach the callbacks https://jsfiddle.net/m3uqenhb/2/